# How can I use SublimeLinter jshint on different SyntaxDefinition?

Tags: sublimetext2, extendscript, sublimelinter

I'm trying to write a Sublime Syntax Definition for ExtendScript but don't want to loose the possibility to use the SublimeLinter plugin. So how can I tell SublimeLinter that he should use jshint not only on scope `source.js` but also on my scope `source.jsx`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select `Preferences->Package Settings->SublimeLinter->Settings - User` and to add to it the following:

```json
"sublimelinter_syntax_map":
{
    "Python Django": "python",
    "Ruby on Rails": "ruby",
    "C++": "c"
    "ExtendScript": "JavaScript"
}
```

and you should be all set. If it doesn't work, try changing `JavaScript` to all lowercase - the docs are a little unclear as to which is correct.